# ¿Cómo encontrar carácteres no latinos en MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en `MySQL 5.7.23-23`:

```
CREATE TABLE `lh_antiphon` (
  `antiphonID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `antiphon` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`antiphonID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `antiphon` (`antiphon`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2104 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

En la columna `antiphon` puede haber contenido con carácteres como: `§, ℟, ℣, †, ƞ, α` (son muchos carácteres como estos posibles, algunos del griego, otros son símbolos) y quiero encontrar qué filas tienen contenido con dichos carácteres.

He intentando esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM lh_antiphon WHERE antiphon NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9.,-]';
```

Pero no me está funcionando. ¿Qué consulta debería ejecutar para encontrar esas filas, **tomando en cuenta mi versión de MySQL**? La idea es encontrar todo el contenido que no sean letras latinas, acentuadas o no, signos de puntuación, guiones, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrías comparar una cadena convertida a la codificación deseada versus la original, puedes usar el [charset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-charsets.html) `cp850` (DOS West European) que [incluye las vocales acentuadas](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp850.html):

```
INSERT INTO lh_antiphon (antiphon) 
  values ('Sólo caracteres ascii'), 
         ('Aca hay otros §, ℟, ℣, †, ƞ, α'),
         ('palabra');

select antiphon
       from lh_antiphon
       where CONVERT(antiphon USING cp850) <> antiphon

antiphon
-------------------------------
Aca hay otros §, ℟, ℣, †, ƞ, α
```

En cuanto a la expresión regular, en realidad deberías buscar negando el patrón, pero no con el `NOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM lh_antiphon WHERE antiphon REGEXP '[^A-Za-z0-9.,\\sáéíóú-]';
```

Es decir, las cadenas que incluyen cualquier carácter fuera  del patrón indicado. Por otro lado, con `NOT REGEXP <patron>` ocurre que nunca se verifica, por que todas las cadenas de tu ejemplo tienen algún caracter que si coincide con el patrón.

Comment: Ahi edité mi respuesta, prueba usando un charset que incluya  los acentos  o la alternativa de agregar los caracteres acentuados en la expresión regular.

Comment: Dos cambios, el charset al cp850 y el patrón que ahora debería funcionar, los guiones literales debe ir  al principio o al final del patrón, sino se interpreta como un rango, y agregué al espacio como un caracter más.

Comment: Lo que me ha funcionado ha sido `where CONVERT(antiphon USING cp850) <> antiphon`, con `REGEXP` no ha habido forma de que funcione.